# How to compose functions in go?

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure out how to set up middlewares, and right now I've got something like:

```
func applyMiddleware(h *Handle) *Handle {
   return a(b(c(h)))
}
```

Is there a way to "compose" these functions so I can just pass a list of Handle(s) and it will return the composed function?

Comment: they must be `func(*Handle) *Handle` otherwise it is not valid go code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use a slice

https://play.golang.org/p/DrEnGkIEbU3

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(v(v(v(0))))
    fmt.Println(compose(v, v, v)(0))
}
func v(i int) int {
    return i + 1
}
func compose(manyv ...func(int) int) func(int) int {
    return func(i int) int {
        for _, v := range manyv {
            i = v(i)
        }
        return i
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is actually piping and not composing. The code remains the same except that the order of evaluation is right-to-left. The innermost function is executed first and then the outer ones follow. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: no this is commonly accepted as function composition. Piping is when you connect a data flow producer to a data flow consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the introduction of generics in Go 1.18, you can define the following generic function for composing two arbitrary functions:

```
func compose[A any, B any, C any](f func(A) B, g func(B) C) func(A) C {
    return func(a A) C {
        return g(f(a))
    }
}
```

The order of composition of `compose` above is *left to right*, i.e., `compose(f, g)` returns the function "*g* after *f*" or *g* ∘ *f*, equivalent to `g . f` in Haskell and to `f >> g` in F# or Elm.

In other words, the input to the resulting function – `compose(f, g)` – is fed into `f`, then `f`'s output is fed into `g`, whose output is the final result:

[image: order of composition of compose(f, g)]

---

Let's first define the type `Adapter` for representing the type of functions you want to compose:

```
type Adapter = func(*Handle) *Handle
```

With `compose` and `Adapter`, you can now define `composeAdapters` for composing an arbitrary number of these `Adapter`s functions:

```
func composeAdapters(adapters ...Adapter) Adapter {
    composition := func(h *Handle) *Handle {
        return h
    }
    for _, adapter := range adapters {
        composition = compose(composition, adapter)
    }
    return composition
}
```

Note that `composition` is initialized to the *identity function* for `*Handle`. You can think of it as a *no-op adapter*: it just forwards the input to the resulting composed adapters to the first function to compose in the chain, if any. This also implies that calling `composeAdapters` without any arguments – e.g., `composeAdapters()` – results in the no-op adapter: it performs no action on the input `*Handle`; it just gives it back.

Given the functions `f`, `g`, and `h` of type `Adapter` – i.e., `func(*Handle) *Handle` – `applyMiddleware` can be implemented as:

```
var applyMiddleware = composeAdapters(f, g, h)
```

Note again the order of composition:

[image: order of composition of applyMiddleware]

Answer (score 0):

JFMR's response is the most direct.  However, for folks who like a functional-programming slant ... you could alternatively compose functions by creating a `Functor` interface.

```
// functor via embedding
type Functor[A any, B any, C any] interface {
    fmap(func(A) B) C
}

// holding the "function" type in a way that is compatible with Functor
type Wtf[R any, A any, B any] func(R) A

// implementation/instance of Functor for anonymous functions!
func (g Wtf[R, A, B]) fmap(f func(A) B) Wtf[R, B, A] {
    h := func(t R) B { return f(g(t)) }
    var funout Wtf[R, B, A] = h
    return funout
}
```

In the implementation, the return types was purposely chosen to be the embedded type, `Wtf[R,B,A]`, rather than `fn(R)B` in order to permit the chaining of composition operations.

Then to show how it works ...

```
func main(){
    var f1 Wtf[int, int, int] = func(t int) int { return 1 * t }
    f2 := func(t int) int { return 2 * t }
    f3 := func(t int) int { return 3 * t }
    fmt.Println((f1.fmap(f2).fmap(f3))(7)) // 42 
}
```

Please notice that ordering of the functions is the same that you'd see when using piping operations in other languages (like `f1 |> f2 |> f3`).

The nice thing about this construction is that not only does it allow you to chain operations together, but you can create other implementations of the interface for other data-types.  For example, when applied to collections, it gives you the behavior that you'd expect to see from the functional-programming `map`-function (not to be confused with Go's function of the same name).

A nice thing about this construction is that the only constraint on types is that they're consistent with permitting composition.